# Problems installing PyPy and IPyKernel

Tags: conda, jupyter-lab, pypy, conda-forge

So first a bit of context...

I'm trying to set up a JupyterLab environment where I can (reasonably seamlessly) change between Python kernels to assess code performance. Target kernels would be standard CPython (Python 3 - mainly latest versions) and PyPy. I'm using conda to manage my environments.

I have set up a JupyterLab environment (installing JupyterLab in base conda environment) and by creating various conda environments based on different CPython versions (in which I have install ipykernel as well), I can easily change run time kernel in JupyterLab. So far so good.

So, to complete the endeavour, I just need to create a PyPy environment in conda (as per [PyPy instructions](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html)) and install `ipykernel` in it. It appears impossible to do this.

My expectation is that I create a PyPy environment as per [PyPy instructions](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html), add ipykernel to it and I will be able to switch to a PyPy based kernel in JupyterLab (as I have successfully done with CPython environments). My expectations are not met!

I start by creating a PyPy environment in conda:

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -c conda-forge -n pypy-env pypy python=3.8
```

It takes a while, but appears to work:

```
(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\tools\miniconda3
py-311                   C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\py-311
pypy-env                 C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda activate pypy-env
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.8.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (a9dbdca6, May 11 2023, 16:56:34)
[PyPy 7.3.11 with MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Attempting to add ipykernel (necessary to enable kernel switching in JupyterLab) fails after quite a spirited attempt and highlights MANY conflicts (abbreviated for convenience):

```
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda install ipykernel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
pip -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=3.0.8,<4.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
...
...
Package six conflicts for:
ipykernel -> packaging -> six
pip -> html5lib -> six[version='>=1.9']
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Although advised by PyPy, the `strict` channel priority looks to be causing issues. Setting it back from `strict` to the default `flexible`

```
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda config --set channel_priority flexible
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

enables seemingly satisfactory installation:

```
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda install ipykernel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
...
...
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
```

However, starting JupyterLab (JL) and selecting the new pypy-env kernel fails, as the JL logs confirm:

```
CONDA_PREFIX=C:\tools\miniconda3
C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py:23: UserWarning: Could not import submodules
  warnings.warn("Could not import submodules")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\Lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\Lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .connect import *  # noqa
  File "C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jupyter_client import write_connection_file
ImportError: cannot import name 'write_connection_file' from 'jupyter_client' (C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\pypy-env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py)
```

Changing to the JL kernel to a CPython conda environment (aside from a few warnings in the JL log) appears to work fine (and executes code correctly in the notebook):

```
CONDA_PREFIX=C:\tools\miniconda3
This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
[I 2023-06-30 18:35:24.069 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 834d68cd-6153-4f99-9beb-ded2e414bc14.
[I 2023-06-30 18:35:24.088 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 834d68cd-6153-4f99-9beb-ded2e414bc14.
[I 2023-06-30 18:35:24.111 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 834d68cd-6153-4f99-9beb-ded2e414bc14.
```

[image]

So, in summary, following PyPy's advice of `strict` conda channel priority makes it impossible to install `ipykernel`. Ignoring PyPy's advice regarding conda channel priority and sticking with the `flexible` default enables what appears to be a successful install but in fact is inoperable (at least in the context of `ipykernel` and JupyterLab).

**Anyone have any suggestions how to rectify this situation and enable a functional install of PyPy that works with `ipykernel` and JupyterLab?**

Comment: Do you have the default channel  listed before conda-forge in your condarc? Then using `strict` would prefer default, which does not support pypy. You should __only__ use the conda-forge channel for PyPy packages.

Comment: Could you list your packages via `conda list` and make sure they are coming from conda-forge?

Comment: Mattip...first....thanks for taking the time to respond! I checked my .condarc file, and it was suprisingly sparse...just the entry "channel_priority: flexible" - a consequence of me setting this from the command line. So, no doubt basic defaults apply as per https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: I checked the env list on the pypy environment, and it was clear there wasn't a uniformity of conda-forge packages. So I'll explain what I did, but it'll need more than the 400 or so characters this comment field gives me!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so further to mattip's suggestion, I checked the list of installed packages in the pypy environment and not all the packages were from `conda-forge`. Accordingly I deleted the environment and started again. Before building a new environment, I checked my .condarc file contents:

```
channel_priority: flexible
```

and the channel URL's being used by conda via `conda info`:

```
    channel URLs : 
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64                    
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch                  
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64                 
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch                     
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64                     
    https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

and the `default channels` via `conda config --show`:

```
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2
```

This time, I made sure I forced conda-forge channel at every stage of environment creation:

```
(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda create -c conda-forge  --name pypy-env pypy python=3.8
(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda activate pypy-env
(pypy-env) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda install -c conda-forge ipykernel
```

The initial environment creation command installed exclusively `conda-forge` sourced packages. However there was one exception with the **jupyter_core** when I installed `ipykernel`:

```
jupyter_client     conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_client-8.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
jupyter_core       pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_core-5.3.0-py38haa95532_0
libsodium          conda-forge/win-64::libsodium-1.0.18-h8d14728_1
```

Notwithstanding this, **this approach worked**. I subsequently ran jupyterlab, and could successfully select my **pypy-env** environment and run code in it.

[image: Screenshot of JupyterLab]

Success!

This exercise has created some further questions, but these can be for separate posts